# Counting problem about sub-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, probability-theory

EDIT (along the lines suggested by @sea turtles):

Given a prime power $q$ and a positive integer $x\gt q$, how many subsets $A\subseteq{\bf F}_2^q$ have size $x$ and contain a subset $B\subseteq A$ with $q+1$ elements, such that for each subset $C\subseteq B$ with $q$ elements, the vectors of $C$ are linearly independent over ${\bf F}_2$?

ORIGINAL:

Assume that we have n $\times$ q matrix  where $n=2^q-1$ and each  row $\in \mathbb{F_{2}^q}$ (Note that this matrix contains all vector space of $\mathbb{F_{2}^q}$ ). How many subsets of rows with cardinality x ( higher that $q$) satisfying that contains at least one set of $q+1$ rows such that each $q$ rows of it have rank $q$?

Comment: Very unclear. What set do the entries in the matrix come from? What does "this matrix contains all vector space of ${\bf F}^q_2$" mean? Maybe you could illustrate with a small example. Or tell us where this problem comes from.

Comment: Here is what I think your question is, removing the superfluous matrix organization: *How many subsets $A\subseteq \Bbb F_2^q$ have size $x$ and contain a subset $B\subseteq A$ such that $|B|=q+1$ and for each subset $C\subseteq B$ with $|C|=q$ the vectors of $C$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb F_2$?* One would probably want to count the unordered vector space bases and then invoke inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask exactly what sea turtles said.

Comment: If that's what you wanted to ask, then please edit your question so it asks that. People shouldn't need to go through the comments to find the question.

Comment: Never mind, I did it myself.